# How to get the smaller value of a column based in other column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the matrix bellow and I`m try get the shortest time on each route (Downtown & Countryside) but I can't find how to do that using Pandas.

[image]

```
dict_ = {'City of origin':["Oxford","Oxford","Oxford","London","London","London","Manchester","Manchester","Manchester"],
     'Destination city':["London","London","London","Manchester","Manchester","Manchester","Oxford","Oxford","Oxford"],
     'Downtown':[2,1,6,1,4,5,2,8,4],
     'Countryside':[4,8,7,2,8,8,3,10,15]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)
```

expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with these lines:

```
df = df.groupby(["City of origin", "Destination city"]).agg({"Downtown":"min", "Countryside":'min'})
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) will probably do the trick:

```
df.groupby(["City of origin", "Destination city"]).min()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use`groupby` + `agg`:

```
df.groupby(['City of origin', 'Destination city']).agg({'Downtown': 'min', 'Countryside': 'min'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You find the min on one column and save it to a dataframe.

Then do it for the second column.

And then merge both dataframes together.

```
df1 = df.groupby(["city of origin","destination city"]).min("dowtown")
df2 = df.groupby(["city of origin","destination city"]).min("countryside")
df = df1.merge(df2, how="inner", on=["city of origin","destination city"])
```